# Safari Networking is using all my memory

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, memory

[image]

Safari Networking is using more memory than I even have on my computer (only 16 GB RAM).

This process, Safari Networking, seems to be constantly rising in memory usage. From the time I opened stack exchange to the time I took the screenshot it had raised from 15.48 to 19.03 GB, and as I am writing this it is at 20.41 GB.

Also, it has the highest CPU usage, of about 90% (kernel_task is similar here).

What's going on and how can I "fix" this? (Does it need fixing?)

Comment: What happens after a relaunch/reboot? Does it require you to open a specific web page before it takes off? I checked mine... currently 134 MB with over 40 open tabs & 7 days uptime.